# Easymock with dao

Tags: junit, dao, easymock

Let's assume that i have a Dao class with a method that establishes connection and reads int from database.

```
public class Dao {
    public static final Dao INSTANCE = new Dao();

    public int getSomething() {
        //connection
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And i have a Servlet with such code inside.

```
int i = Dao.INSTANCE.getSomething();
```

The problem is that i don't know how to mock this Dao.INSTANCE call...
If it was for example a servlet with session. I could make it like this.

```
Session s = EasyMock.createMock(Session.class);
expect(request.getSession()).andReturn(s);
```

but i am not able to make it like this

```
Dao dao = EasyMock.createMock(Dao.class);
expect(Dao.INSTANCE).andReturn(dao);
```

Comment: So you want to mock the Dao class correct?

Comment: Yes, i want to mock the Dao class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the dao an instance variable, and then you can easily mock it:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    Dao dao = Dao.INSTANCE;
}

MyServlet servlet = new MyServlet();
servlet.dao = EasyMock.createMock(Dao.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you change the code so calling a method will return a singleton. Such as

```
public class Dao {
    public static Dao singleton;

    public static Dao getInstance(){
         if(singleton == null){
               singleton = new Dao();
         }
     return singleton;

    }

    public int getSomething() {
        //connection
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And after that mock `getInstance` using PowerMock.
Take a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) for how.